# Can't work out how to align logo and nav in a row using CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to align a logo and navigation bar in one row across the top of a website using CSS grid.

I've written out the code but can't work out what I'm doing wrong as to why it's not working: https://codepen.io/chloewb/pen/wRRewQ

```css
     .logo{
    grid-area: logo;
    background:white;}
    .navi{
     grid-area: navi;
    background:Yellow;}
    .section1{
     grid-area: features;
    background:LightSalmon;}
    .section2{
     grid-area: technology;
    background:PaleTurquoise;}
    .section3{
     grid-area: pricing;
    background:LightPink;}
    .section4{
    grid-area: email;
    background:PaleGreen;}
  
    .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat (5, auto);
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
     grid-template-areas:
      "logo navi navi"
      "features features features"
       "technology technology technology"
       "pricing pricing pricing"
       "email email email";}
```

Comment: it seems like this code can be represented as SO snippet.

Comment: Post more details or an image of how you want it to look.

Comment: You are setting the `.container` as a `grid`, this affects its direct children, `header` and `section`, your `logo` and `navi` are children of `header`, thus not affected by the grid layout

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that, when you use `display: grid` on a container element, its direct children will become `grid-items`, and to these items is that the grid layout you build will apply.

So let's say we have the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child-1">
        <div class="child-2"></div>
        <div class="child-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-1"></div>
    <div class="child-1"></div>
    <div class="child-1"></div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.container{
        display: grid;
    }
```

Then only the `child-1` will become grid items and be able to get properties like `grid-area` applied to them; everything else inside `.child-1`, like `.child-2` will behave normally, as if there's no Grid. Unless you also specify the `.child-1` element to be a grid with `display: grid`.

In your case, you `header` element is a direct child of the `.container` element, so it is a grid item and can be positioned on any place on the grid, but the `logo` and `navi` elements are children of `header`, so the grid layout does not apply to them. You would either have to take them out of the `header` so the rules you wrote take effect, or create another grid in the header and let it use the full first row. See this example and notice how the nesting of the elements affect them.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "logo navi navi";
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.navi {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  grid-area: navi;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="navi">Nav</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="navi">Nav</div>
  </header>
</div>
```